# RF100 Settings after reinstalling firmware

Tags: ultimaker-cura, firmware, homing

I have an RF100 v.1 printer with stock software (again) onboard.

After my attempt of changing firmware, the X-axis motor decided to stray printhead away out of the borders of the printer and somehow motor wires broke out of the adapter. 
I fixed the wires and reverted to stock firmware, though now whenever I auto-home or press "Home" button on Ultimaker Cura, printhead goes wild top and left reaching borders and starts buzzing like crazy.

current condition:

1. Head is TOP LEFT with X=100 and Y=100 on the table being under head Z=0;
2. screenshot

Even with these beautiful tiny settings, I cannot print anything because printhead goes too far TOP RIGHT by itself.
Ideas?

Comment: you speak of a screenshot, which is missing. Please add it.

Answer (score -1):

Everything was fixed by thorough googling and flipping the whole wire-set of the motor. It started to twirl in a right direction.
Sorry for the time

Comment: Please make some time to make a proper answer and update the question with relevant pictures, other people may benefit from it. As is now this question and it's answer has no value for storing as a reference for others.

Comment: Hi Rodion, and welcome to SE 3D Printing! Whilst your answer may be technically correct, it *is* rather terse, and, as such, it has been recommended for deletion, unfortunately. If you could expand it then you may get a more positive response. I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted answers to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [answering](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/answering) questions, in particular [answer], and take the [tour] for more information on how stack exchange works. Thanks :-)